# how iterate between divs jquery

Tags: jquery

i have doubt about how can i iterate into a group of div, my problem it's that i have this selector

```
$('.imagePanel')
```

this selector give a  group of div that belong's to that class. Also i know that with the method `length` i can know how divs are. the problem it's that i wanna know if i can storage in a array each div to know what's it's the div which it's clicking by the user in other words to this

```
$(".imagePanel").click(setElement);

function setElement() {

for (var i = 0; i < $('.imagePanel').length; i++) {

    //validate in the loop if it's in the div that click the user
    if (this.id == $("#"i).id) {

        if (!$(this).data('selected')) {
            $(this).css('border', '2px solid black').data('selected', true);
        }
        else {
            $(this).stop(true, true).data('selected', false);
        }
    }

}
}
```

**edit**

To be more specific, in the group of div i need that only one have the style, if you click in one an then in other, the last div that you make the click it's the one with the style the other div's need's to clear the style

**don't want this**

[image]

Comment: out of curiosity, what are you 'really' trying to implement? Something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/LS4JV/ ?

Comment: @Shawn Chin sometinhg like that but with images

Comment: I would suggest that you give more details about what you're trying to achieve, rather than focussing on how to make your current solution work. In other words, try to avoid the XY Problem (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: @Shawn Chin i need to set the the only in the div that you make click, and remove from the other. the idea it's that the always have one of the divs the style

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/LS4JV/1/

Comment: @Shawn Chin exactly thanks!!! put it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the updated question (see comment thread on question), you do not need to iterate through all the divs.

Just bind a function to `click` which adds your desired css class to `$(this)` (the clicked element).

One way ensure that only one item is selected would be to keep a cache of the currently selected element and remove the associated class from it when something else is clicked.

Example:

```
var selected_xyz = null; 
$('.xyz').click(function() {
    t = $(this);
    if (selected_xyz != t) {
        if (selected_xyz != null) {
           selected_xyz.removeClass("selected");   
        }
        t.addClass("selected");
        selected_xyz = t;
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LS4JV/1/

Answer (score 6):

`this` will get the element upon which you are clicking:

```
$(".imagePanel").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this); //<--good practice: cache
    if (!$this.data('selected')) {
        $this.css('border', '2px solid black').data('selected', true);
    } else {
        $this.stop(true, true).data('selected', false);
    }
});
```

You could refactor the above for even greater brevity:

```
$(".imagePanel").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this); //<--good practice: cache
    $this.data('selected')? $this.stop(true, true).data('selected', false) :
                            $this.css('border', '2px solid black').data('selected', true);
});
```

If you wanted to iterate over the collection for some other reason, then [jQuery each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) would be what you would need.

```
$(".imagePanel").each(function(){
    //do something
});
```

It is not necessary for you in this circumstance, however.

Comment: To add onto this, @Jorge, there is no point in comparing `this` against all the divs with the same click handler to find which one was clicked, as `this` is always the clicked element

Comment: @matt b that's nice but i need to remove the style if there another div with that style. Because i need to select only one div

Comment: Haven't you swapped the `?`/`:` in the ternary operator by chance?

Comment: @bazmegakapa: Whoops! Good spot

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".imagePanel").click(function(){
    if(!$(this).data('selected')){
        $(this).css('border', '2px solid black').data('selected', true);
    }else{
         $(this).stop(true, true).data('selected', false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: its a good thing to know how to each a set but this is not a "good" answer for this question as the OP just needs a click event added not to loop through

Comment: Fair enough. Misunderstood the original question :)